What is this Python list containing all tokens from my code?
If I run this code in Python 3.10:
import gc


def main():
    a = 23764723
    ref = gc.get_referrers(a)[0]
    print(ref)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


I get the following output:
['gc', 'main', 'a', 23764723, 'ref', 'gc', 'get_referrers', 'a', 0, 'print', 'ref', '__main__', '__name__', 'main']

What is this list, that seems to contain all of the literals(?) from my code? Is there an explanation in the Python docs anywhere?

I think it gives you all of the things that are defined in your current code. I think if you added a new variable it will add it also ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#:~:text=gc.get_referrers   ... this is explanation from the docs

@Mohammedalmalki I don't think that link answers the question. You've linked to get_referrers, which doesn't give an explanation of this list.

how exactly are you running this? Are you running this in some kind of REPL?

I suspect this is some list used internally by the runtime, perhaps during the parsing of the source code itself, that keeps track of constants and variable names.

I seem to have cause confusion here by making the code example a bit unclear. To be clear, I'm asking for an explanation of the first item in the list returned by get_referrers, rather than the list returned by get_referrers itself.

@juanpa.arrivillaga I think you are correct, but I'm still unclear as to which list this is. You mention main.code.co_consts in another comment, which is what I thought it might be, but it turns out not to be that.

According to this post, and after trying different things with the code, the first item returned by the get_referrers 's first item is just a list of references of the objects in the global and current scope of the current respective python file which holds the object.

This isn't what I get on Python 3.10.

I only get this output on Python 3.8 or lower. It's something the old parser implementation uses, not the new PEG parser. Are you sure you used Python 3.10?

@user2357112 Yes, sorry, you're right. I must have run this on Python 3.7.  Python 3.10 gives a similar (but different) list.

First off, that doesn't look like Python 3.10 output. That output should only happen on Python 3.8 or lower, due to parser changes. 3.10 produces a very different list.
The list you're seeing is the list of objects associated with the arena used to produce your code's abstract syntax tree. Quoting Python/pyarena.c:
/* The arena manages two kinds of memory, blocks of raw memory
   and a list of PyObject* pointers.  PyObjects are decrefed
   when the arena is freed.
*/

Most of the memory used by Python/ast.c is handled by an arena. In particular, every time it needs a new identifier:
static identifier
new_identifier(const char *n, struct compiling *c)
{
    ...
    if (PyArena_AddPyObject(c->c_arena, id) < 0) {

numeric constant:
    case NUMBER: {
        ...
        if (PyArena_AddPyObject(c->c_arena, pynum) < 0) {

or string literal:
/* Make a Constant node, but decref the PyUnicode object being added. */
static expr_ty
make_str_node_and_del(PyObject **str, struct compiling *c, const node* n)
{
    ...
    if (PyArena_AddPyObject(c->c_arena, s) < 0) {

it calls PyArena_AddPyObject to add the identifier, number, or string literal to the arena's list of objects.
When you run your file, execution goes through the pyrun_file function, which looks like this:
static PyObject *
pyrun_file(FILE *fp, PyObject *filename, int start, PyObject *globals,
           PyObject *locals, int closeit, PyCompilerFlags *flags)
{
    PyArena *arena = PyArena_New();
    if (arena == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    mod_ty mod;
    mod = PyParser_ASTFromFileObject(fp, filename, NULL, start, 0, 0,
                                     flags, NULL, arena);
    if (closeit) {
        fclose(fp);
    }

    PyObject *ret;
    if (mod != NULL) {
        ret = run_mod(mod, filename, globals, locals, flags, arena);
    }
    else {
        ret = NULL;
    }
    PyArena_Free(arena);

    return ret;
}

First, it parses your code into an AST, populating the list you see as a side effect:
    mod = PyParser_ASTFromFileObject(fp, filename, NULL, start, 0, 0,
                                     flags, NULL, arena);

Then it calls run_mod to compile the AST and execute the resulting code object:
    if (mod != NULL) {
        ret = run_mod(mod, filename, globals, locals, flags, arena);
    }
    else {
        ret = NULL;
    }

And only after your code has been executed, the arena is freed, freeing the associated list:
    PyArena_Free(arena);


Finally, someone who actually knows what they're talking about! I know get_referrers is for debugging only, but it's odd the documentation (even for 3.8) doesn't mention this wrinkle.


First off, that doesn't look like Python 3.10 output. That output should only happen on Python 3.8 or lower, due to parser changes. 3.10 produces a very different list.

@user2357112 You're right. I somehow ran this on 3.7. The output from 3.10 is different, but contains similar things, so I assume your answer still applies.

@Neil: Yeah, it's still the arena's list on Python 3.10. The new parser implementation just uses it differently.

if i recall correctly get_referrers gives you a list of all object that directly refer to the value (not variable) you try to ask for, in your case that would be your main file referring to the value 23764723 in addition you would list all other things your main file refers to as well as whatever other objects refer to that number
you can try something like
a = {'x':[],'y':0}
ref = gc.get_referrers(a['x'])[0]

which prints the entire value of a (trying this with a['y'] would be checking what refers to the value 0 which besides a additionally returns a whole host of other objects)
in this case you only get a as only this value refers to the unique instance of []

Edit added since poster said that they needed to know why gc was on the list. It is basically because the gc module is referring to the argument, it is always there because it has the reference in execution.
First of all, there is documentation on this. Secondly, it does not include every literal on your code. It just refers to the list of objects that have references to the input objects. However, they need to support garbage collection and those that do not support them are not found.
What is gc.get_referrers()?
Instead of getting every literal on your code, this function returns a list of objects that refer to any of the arguments. In other words, it will give a list of every object that has references to the input object which has garbage collection enabled.
For example, let's say you use gc.get_referrers() on a integer, or any other data type (or even parts of it), you will get a lot of references, especially core Python elements. That is because a lot of objects will point to integers in your program or Python itself with core elements.
Here is another example: using it on the int data type will also return everything on your program that holds or uses a integer and also core Python elements that are used for the execution of your program.
Now, we can also test this by doing another test: using it on numbers that your program or core Python parts do not have. We can use it on a unknown number that you are not currently using.
>>> import gc
>>> print(gc.get_referrers(1000000000))
[['gc', 'get_referrers', 1000000000], (1000000000, None)]

Now, that is a lot less than doing gc.get_referrers() on other data types or others that are used in your program. This is because this number has only been used this one time. Core parts or the program doesn't use these. gc and get_referrers are there since those are being pointed at the program and are being referenced to it.
Why is this used?
Well, this function is not used a lot, with searching it up leading to a few bits of information. However, the official documentation states:
Warning
Care must be taken when using objects returned by get_referrers() because some of them could still be under construction and hence in a temporarily invalid state. Avoid using get_referrers() for any purpose other than debugging.
In other words, you should only use it for debugging and some of the returned objects could be temporarily invalid.
What is that list on your code?
The yielded list were the references of that and most of them were core Python parts.
That question has more into it. It gets everything that has been referenced to that number. Most of them are as mentioned, core Python parts. There is also gc and get_referrers() which are due to the fact that they are being used as references. Then, it also gets the name of the argument and also the value. It also gets print().
The list basically contained those references, one of them being the variable name and the variable reference being a reference.
So, in other words, it gets the core Python functions and parts which are used for the code execution, the name and value of the argument and also gc and the used function.
To sum that all up, the function gets every object which is a reference to the argument (data type, variable etc.) which has garbage collection enabled. These also include Python elements.
Also, common data types or used stuff will have a lot of elements while specific and unknown pieces of data like random integers will have very few items.
Should You Use This?
No, documentation is rare and it can be confusing. While debugging is stated as a reason to use it, temporarily invalid items load too.
Edit to Answer Question
The comment by the poster said that they needed a explanation why the first item (gc) was on the list.
gc will forever be there because gc is referring to the object passed on gc.get_referrers().

It is a list of all the objects that refer to 'a'
gc = Garbage Collector interface

gc.get_referrers(*objs)
Return the list of objects that directly refer to any of objs. This function will only locate those containers which support garbage collection; extension types which do refer to other objects but do not support garbage collection will not be found.


Note that objects which have already been dereferenced, but which live in cycles and have not yet been collected by the garbage collector can be listed among the resulting referrers. To get only currently live objects, call collect() before calling get_referrers().


If I add something like x = 3 in the main function the list will contain 'x' and 3. So how do they refer to a?

@Matthias remember you are dealing with objects here and not variables, as an object 'a' has reference to it's creator object, which has references to it created objects.

Since the documentation says "objects that directly refer to any of objs" I find this pretty strange. But I have no other explanation at the moment.

@getsmartt no, that isn't how it works at all.

@juanpa I think Kenzo Staelens may have explained it better in his answer, but by definition link returns all objects referenced to the object.  The effect can be seen by simply replacing ref = gc.get_referrers(a) with ref = gc.get_referrers(gc).  also calling gc.collect() before ref = gc.get_referrers() will remove the second list of dereferenced  objects, leaving only the one list. See also point 4. in the answer here link

@getsmartt that doesn't answer anything in this question. The OP knows what get_referrers  does, they don't understand where that list comes from though.

@getsmartt and specifically, "you are dealing with objects here and not variables, as an object 'a' has reference to it's creator object, which has references to it created objects" is totally incorrect. there is no "creator object". I am 50% certain this is just LLM output

@juanpa.arrivillaga if everything in python is and object, then the class (or function, or whatever) that holds that object is the creator of said object.  Thus main() in, the example given, is the creator of 'a'.  I'm certainly not going to go down the rabbit hole of semantics.

@juanpa.arrivillaga
..."they don't understand where that list comes from though"... I can guarantee it is NOT "some list used internally [...], that keeps track of constants and variable names" Have you read the Python Docs for gc.get_referrers? It answers the question... "Return(s) the list of objects that directly refer to any of objs"

No, it doesn't explain this at all. One of those objects in the list of objects that refers to that int is that list, which also has strings that correspond to various names in the source code. His code did not create that list, so where did it come from? The documentation doesn't answer that. It merely explains that this list refers to that int, which one can see by inspecting the list.

"if everything in python is and object, then the class (or function, or whatever) that holds that object is the creator of said object. Thus main() in, the example given, is the creator of 'a'." that is absolutely 100% incorrect. If it were correct, then get_referrers would return the main function object. You clearly don't understand what is going on here

The function doesn't "hold" the object in any sense. It doesn't even create it, indeed, it is created at compile time in this case. This isn't an issue of semantics, you are simply incorrect.

Note, get_referrers  does return main.__code__.co_consts, that is at position 1 instead of position 0 (main is only printing gc.get_referrers(a)[0], not the whole list of referrers)
